# How to keep signing data with TPM without getting Lockout response?

Tags: c#, tpm

I'm using [TSS.net](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR) to run some tests against the Microsoft TPM simulator. I am able to successfully create a signing key, but can only sign with that key twice. On the 3rd attempt to sign, I get a `Lockout` response.

How do I continue to sign data with this key without getting a `Lockout` response?

## Repro Steps

After starting up the simulator, I run this method once:

```cs
public void ReproStep1()
{
    Tpm2Device tpmDevice = new TcpTpmDevice("127.0.0.1", 2321);

    tpmDevice.Connect();

    var tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);

    tpmDevice.PowerCycle();
    tpm.Startup(Su.Clear);

    var ownerAuth = new AuthValue();

    var keyTemplate = new TpmPublic(TpmAlgId.Sha1, // Name algorithm
        ObjectAttr.UserWithAuth | ObjectAttr.Sign | // Signing key
        ObjectAttr.FixedParent | ObjectAttr.FixedTPM | // Non-migratable 
        ObjectAttr.SensitiveDataOrigin,
        null, // No policy
        new RsaParms(new SymDefObject(),
            new SchemeRsassa(TpmAlgId.Sha256), 2048, 0),
        new Tpm2bPublicKeyRsa());

    var keyAuth = new byte[] {1, 2, 3};

    TpmPublic keyPublic;
    CreationData creationData;
    TkCreation creationTicket;
    byte[] creationHash;

    TpmHandle keyHandle = tpm[ownerAuth].CreatePrimary(
        TpmRh.Owner, // In the owner-hierarchy
        new SensitiveCreate(keyAuth, null), // With this auth-value
        keyTemplate, // Describes key
        null, // Extra data for creation ticket
        new PcrSelection[0], // Non-PCR-bound
        out keyPublic, // PubKey and attributes
        out creationData, out creationHash, out creationTicket); // Not used here

    Console.WriteLine("New public key\n" + keyPublic.ToString());

    TpmHandle persistentHandle = TpmHandle.Persistent(0x5000);

    //Get rid of the stored key (if there is one)
    tpm._AllowErrors().EvictControl(TpmRh.Owner, persistentHandle, persistentHandle);

    //Store the key in NV memory
    tpm.EvictControl(TpmRh.Owner, keyHandle, persistentHandle);
}
```

I can then only run the following method twice before getting a `Lockout` response from the TPM simulator:

```cs
public void ReproStep2()
{
    Tpm2Device tpmDevice = new TcpTpmDevice("127.0.0.1", 2321);

    tpmDevice.Connect();

    var tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);

    var keyAuth = new byte[] {1, 2, 3};

    tpmDevice.PowerCycle();
    tpm.Startup(Su.Clear); //Is this appropriate?

    byte[] message = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ABC");
    TpmHash digestToSign = TpmHash.FromData(TpmAlgId.Sha256, message);

    var persistentHandle = TpmHandle.Persistent(0x5000);

    var signature = tpm[keyAuth].Sign(persistentHandle, // Handle of signing key
        digestToSign, // Data to sign
        null, // Use key's scheme
        TpmHashCheck.Null()) as SignatureRsassa;

    Console.WriteLine("Signature: " + BitConverter.ToString(signature.sig));

    tpm.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. It turns out that not shutting down the TPM cleanly has implications for the dictionary attack prevention mechanism. By adding this at the end of step 2, I was able to call `tpm.Sign(...)` many times:

```cs
tpm.Shutdown(Su.Clear);
```